# Slideshow animation bug

Tags: html, css, css-animations, slideshow

I have slideshow on my page, but I have small bug in animation and I can't find it.
I use slideshow according to this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzAshjkhFQw .
But I want to have only 3 slides not 4.
First 3 slides are ok, but instead of the fourth there is an empty background. I want only 3 slides and after that repeat slideshow.

```css
/* Slider */
.slider {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(121, 0, 0);
}

.slider > * {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  animation: slide 12s infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0%;
  animation-delay: -1s;
  background-image: url(img/slide1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide:nth-child(2) {
  left: 100%;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  background-image: url(img/slide2.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide:nth-child(3) {
  left: 100%;
  animation-delay: 5s;
  background-image: url(img/slide3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}


.slide p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 340px;
  color: #fff;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% { left: 100%; width: 100%; opacity: 1;}
  5% { left: 0%;}
  25% { left: 0%;}
  30% { left: -100%; width: 100%; opacity: 1;} 
  30.0001% { left: -100%; width: 0%; opacity: 0;}
  100% { left: 100%; width: 0%; opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
      <div class="slide">
        <p>Slide1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <p>Slide2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <p>Slide3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the percentages in the animations as well as the timings on the individual slides

```css
@keyframes slide {
  0% { left: 100%; width: 100%; opacity: 1;}
  6.667% { left: 0%;}
  33.334% { left: 0%;}
  40% { left: -100%; width: 100%; opacity: 1;} 
  40.0001% { left: -100%; width: 0%; opacity: 0;}
  100% { left: 100%; width: 0%; opacity: 1;}
}

.slide:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.slide:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 7s;
}
```

The animation was initially designed for 4 slides in 12 seconds, i.e. one slide every 3 seconds. If you want to change that to one slide every 4 seconds, you need to space the animations further apart (change the animation delay), and also change the animation so that the slide is visible for a longer time (multiply each percentage by `4/3`).

This way of animating slides seems really inflexible however, so you might want to look at some other approach, which allows you to add or remove slides more easily.